# Why does my matrix print these (long) numbers , how to fix that?

Tags: c++

This is the code and here is the image of output , i need these output to be only n's and 0 but i have these numbers for some reason. How to fix that and replace these numbers by 0's?

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ5cu.png)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 9;

    int matrix[n][n];
    int x = 1;
// output array element's value

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][0] = x;
            matrix[i][n - 1] = x;
            matrix[i][i] = x;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {

            std::cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std: cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting typo at `std: cout << "\n";`. `std::` is what you most likely intended, but what you got was label for use with `goto`.

Comment: Do you think you're initializing all your elements to specific values?  Look at your first set of nested loops carefully: what is it doing?  (Hint: what is the inner loop doing?)

Comment: If you need to define the size of the matrix at run time, then I would recommend using [`std::array<std::array<int, n>, n>`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/) instead. You might even go so far as to make a `Matrix` class built around it, if you think you might need to.

Comment: I would also avoid using the `using namespace std;` scope modifier. It brings in all of the members of `std` as declared in any headers you include, which tends to pollute the namespace of your program.

Answer (score 2):

> i need these output to be only n's and 0

- For `0` to be guaranteed to appear, you need to initialize `matrix` (or explicitly assign `0` to the rest of the elements). This is simply done with `int matrix[n][n]{};` ([*zero initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization)). Reading uninitialized values, like you currently do, makes the program have *undefined behavior* and printing "garbage" values is one possible outcome.
- For `n`s to appear, you need to assign the elements the value held by `n`. You currently assign the value of `x` to the elements in `matrix`.
- The inner assigning loop, `j`, doesn't do anything but repeating the same thing 9 times. Just remove it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    constexpr int n = 9;           // int n = 9; makes `matrix` a non-standard VLA

    int matrix[n][n]{};            // zero initialization

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        matrix[i][0] = n;      // n
        matrix[i][n - 1] = n;  // n
        matrix[i][i] = n;      // n
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            std::cout << matrix[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 
9 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 
9 0 9 0 0 0 0 0 9 
9 0 0 9 0 0 0 0 9 
9 0 0 0 9 0 0 0 9 
9 0 0 0 0 9 0 0 9 
9 0 0 0 0 0 9 0 9 
9 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 9 
9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9
```

Answer (score 1):

The code does not initialise the values of the matrix, apart from a few places. You need to write zeros everywhere else, otherwise you get whatever data was in the memory beforehand (strictly this is 'undefined behaviour', and the program could do anything, but in practice you will print out whatever happened to be in the memory the program uses before it ran)